# MST-Prim implemented by a min priority queue

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

if MST is executed on unconnected graphs what will it execute? I thought it won't execute since it is unconnected but since it is being implemented by min priority queue, will that affect the results?

Comment: What do you mean by "is being implemented by min priority queue"?

Comment: the MST is implemented by a min priority queue

Answer (score 0):

Since the graph is unconnected, it won't find a MST for the whole graph (because there is no tree that spans the entire graph). Rather, Prim's algorithm will find the MST for the connected component of your specified source vertex.